# Is headless testing possible with Opera browser in Selenium with C#

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, opera

I'd like to hide opera with selenium while it's working in the background.

I understood this is possible both with chrome and IE. I wonder if that's possible even with opera, unluckily I didn't find any resources online.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately headless is not supported by Opera.

Also I have noted that Opera will not be supported in Selenium 4.

[What is new in Selenium 4](https://blog.testproject.io/2019/05/01/open-source-selenium-4-test-automation/)

> **Support for Opera** and PhantomJS browsers has been **removed**, since the
> WebDriver implementations for these browsers are no longer under
> active development.

> So, would you have to create manual tests for
> Opera browser? And what about Headless Test Executions? Well, since
> Opera is built using Chromium open source project (The project behind
> Chrome browser), the behavior of Chrome and Opera should be very
> similar. Hence, there are fewer chances of having different behaviors
> and you can simply test Chrome as the Opera browser. And you can still
> automate Chrome as it is still supported of course. And as for
> Headless Tests, you can use Chrome Headless or Firefox Headless
> instead of PhantomJS.